# How can I save data using angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I use JSON or it's not possible by means of Angular?

I want to change data and want it to be changed after refreshing. What should I use?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean by "save data". You can retain data on the client-side, as long as the user doesn't clear it, with one of the [web storage APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). On the server-side you can use a database to keep data more permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON or Angular doesn't save data. It can act as a asynchronous  bridge to your backend, allowing you to save data using the backend.

With 2-way data binding, you can reflect changes in your model to the front-end immediately. You can store the data wherever you want, Mongo, MySQL, or even the browser's localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store data for the same session and when you refresh the page you can pull the data back from session storage and change it.

You don't really have to use any angular for that.